# Can I protect against keylogging by using the mouse?

Tags: keyloggers

Can I protect against keylogging by using the mouse? For example, to enter the password `hunter2`, I might do the following:

1. type `ttter2`
2. select the first `tt` and press <kbd>← Backspace</kbd>
3. type `hun`

To a keylogger, it would like like I typed `tt`<kbd>← Backspace</kbd>`ter2hun`, or `ttterhun`. Would this provide adequate protection, or are keyloggers able to follow mouse gestures, clicking, selecting etc., so they would catch password still?

Comment: I would like to think this will be useful in *some* circumstances. However, it might depend on how much the intruder wants to get into the system. 

On an unrelated note, how much trust do you have that the machine does *not* have a keylogger?

Comment: This "works" only against naive attackers. The keylogger will still pick up the maximum possible password length AND all characters contained in the password, even if it can't follow gestures.

Comment: I do this when typing in payment-card details. It might be fairly useless, but it can't hurt.

Comment: Not to mention, an attacker could record mouse movements as easily as key presses.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A lot of keyloggers are smart enough to catch this. Not only do they log the keys being physically pressed, but they also log the contents of password boxes whenever window messages are processed, or when browser forms are posted. They also often capture small blocks of the screen around the mouse cursor, to catch cases like this.

Comment: So they're not *literally* only keyloggers, then?

Comment: 90% of the time these days, no. They usually have various other features: remote access trojans, session / cookie stealers, file stealers, etc.

Comment: The one thing this *might* still fool is an inline hardware keylogger.

Comment: Is there any alternative word for keylogger that is more descriptive of what it actually does? The word fooled me into expecting them to be less sophisticated than they really are.

Comment: @gerrit: Screen-scrapers, I/O sniffers...

Comment: @gerrit Trojan is probably the best term, since it (usually) refers to anything that steals content these days. The original term was for any type of malware that masqueraded as or inside something legitimate, but that covers most malware these days.

Comment: @Iszi not when it's on the USB cable going to hub both the keyboard and the mouse are plugged into... I'm considering how an iMac tend to be setup with the mouse plugged into the USB hub built into the apple keyboard.

Comment: @Polynomial Well, trojan specifically refers to something the user installed thinking it was something else or partly was something else.

Comment: @ewanm89 That's what it *used to* refer to. These days malware such as Zeus is considered a trojan, despite the fact that the delivery / installation mechanism need not be trojan-like.

Answer (score 3):

It really just depends on how advanced the said keylogger is. Some keyloggers collect data from password boxes when the form is submitted, and some monitor when the keys are pressed. Some keyloggers can be really advanced and even record mouse movements, and your screen. If you do have an unwanted keylogger, I'd take time to try and eradicate it, instead of try to trick it. You don't want to take chances with malware.

Answer (score 1):

Most are more complex than this, but even a limited key logger would still pick up enough information to be able to drastically reduce the entropy of guessing your password since it would be known what characters compose your password and would just be a matter of figuring out what to discard.

Comment: If I enter my password entirely by pasting in characters, a primitive keylogger would be lost, wouldn't it?

Comment: If you pulled it entirely from pre-existing text, then yes, the very most basic would be lost, but that's probably less than 5% (WAG) of keyloggers.  It's pretty easy to inspect windows elements and the clipboard.  In short, it isn't really worth the effort it takes.  Proactive prevention and two factor authentication (one time use keys) are a far better protection.

Answer (score 0):

I perceive this as very cumbersome  (moreso as I get older and mouse precision declines).  I think that cost benefit analysis would suggest that reducing the probability of keyloggers would be a higher value strategy.